# when i clean and build android project in eclipse it delete bin folder and gen folder and regenerate empty gen and bin folder

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

when i clean and build android project in eclipse it delete bin folder and gen folder contents and does not recreate it just create empty folder gen and bin why it is happening I search lot but didn't get solution similar to this issue.

please help me to solve this issue.
after clean build when i run my application it shows this message in console

```
.[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] Android Launch! 
[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-13 17:20:26 - courieryallatracking] Could not find tracking.apk!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I solve the issue because I had not installed build tool and because of that it was not generating gen and bin folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these steps

1.close and open your android project

2.close and clean your eclipse

```
./eclipse -clean
```

3.right click your project > **Android Tools** > **Add Support Library**

[image]

Comment: thanks fo ur reply but it was somthing else  i.e At last I solve the issue because I had not installed build tool and because of that it was not generating gen and bin folder contents.